# Cannot show the range value change inside bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grails, popover

I have a bootstap popover and inside it is a form.
Inside the form I have a range input. I can see the value change in the console.
However I am unable to append the value to the element.

In GSP page,

```
<div id="optionsContainer">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a data-placement="left" data-toggle="popover"
                data-title="Options" data-container="body" type="button"  
                data-html="true" href="#" id="login"></br><span><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>&nbsp &nbsp</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
        <form action="xxx/index" method="post" >

                    <label>fade time: </label>
                    <label id="fadeTimeText"></label><br/>
                    <input type="range" id="fadeTime" name="fadeTime"  min="15" max="300" onchange="updateNumberSliderLabel('fadeTime');" oninput="updateNumberSliderLabel('fadeTime');"><br/>
        </form>
```

In Jquery,

```
 //popover
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
            html: true, 
            content: function() {
                 //  return $($(this).data('contentwrapper')).html();
                  return $('#popover-content').html();
                }
        }); 

    updateNumberSliderLabel('fadeTime');

    function updateNumberSliderLabel(sliderId) {
        var sliderValue = $(".popover-content #" + sliderId).val();
        if (typeof sliderValue === "undefined") {
            //sliderValue = $("#" + sliderId + "Text").html()//document.getElementById(sliderId).value;
            $("#" + sliderId + "Text").text("Hello World");
        }else{
            $("#" + sliderId + "Text").text("***"+ sliderValue);
        }

        console.info("sliderId " + sliderId + "------------" + "sliderValue "+ sliderValue);

    }
```

In fadeTimeText div it always gets Hello World

In console,
sliderId fadeTime------------sliderValue 250

It doesn't change the value of fadeTimeText div. 
Any help would be really appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this problem,
It was just I have to explicitly say that

```
$(".popover-content #" + sliderId + "Text").text(sliderValue);
```

Now the update function looks like,

```
function updateNumberSliderLabel(sliderId) {
    var sliderValue = $(".popover-content #" + sliderId).val();
    if (typeof sliderValue === "undefined") {
        //sliderValue = $("#" + sliderId + "Text").html()//document.getElementById(sliderId).value;
        //$("#" + sliderId + "Text").text("Hello World");
        $(".popover-content #" + sliderId + "Text").text("Hello World");

    }else{
        $(".popover-content #" + sliderId + "Text").text(sliderValue);
    }

}
```